# serialization of float vector in a struct

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization

I have the following code:

```
struct MsgDetectedTarget
{
    int target_id;
    float bbox[4]; // need to change
};
```

in a serialization function :

```
void SerializeToArray(std::vector<char>& buffer, int& dst_len, void* pMsg, int len){
    buffer.resize(HEADER_LENGTH + len);
    // encode message header
    char header[HEADER_LENGTH + 1] = "";
    std::sprintf(header, "%8d", len);

    std::memcpy(&buffer[0], header, HEADER_LENGTH);

    // encode message body
    std::memcpy(&buffer[0]+HEADER_LENGTH, reinterpret_cast<char*>(pMsg), len);

    dst_len = HEADER_LENGTH + len;
}
```

if the data bbox in MsgDetectedTarget is of fixed size, it is easy to do the serialization.

```
  MsgDetectedTarget msg;
  msg.target_id = 1;
  msg.bbox[0] = 0;
  msg.bbox[1] = 0;
  msg.bbox[2] = 500;
  msg.bbox[3] = 500;

  std::vector<char> msgdata;
  int destlen;
  SerializeToArray(msgdata, destlen, &msg, sizeof(msg));
```

***Problem:***

I want to change the bbox in MsgDetectedTarget to be a vector of float, How can I perform corresponding serialization and deserialization?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I would send the size and then the raw data.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisFabre Can you give an example ?

Comment: @Johnnylin Do you really need to invent your own serialization? Why not use an existing serialization library which have already worked it all out? Like for example [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude For Boost serialization, Can you give an example ?

Comment: Follow the link, read the documentation. You will find both tutorials and references.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use Boost serialization, you can do what @Jean-FrancoisFabre suggested. Something like:

```
void SerializeToArray(std::vector<char>& buffer, int& dst_len, MsgDetectedTarget* msg) {
    size_t numFloats = msg->bbox.size();
    auto len = sizeof(int) + sizeof(size_t) + sizeof(float)*numFloats;
    buffer.resize(HEADER_LENGTH + len);

    // encode message header
    char header[HEADER_LENGTH + 1] = "";
    std::sprintf(header, "%8d", len);
    std::memcpy(&buffer[0], header, HEADER_LENGTH);

    // encode target_id
    std::memcpy(&buffer[0] + HEADER_LENGTH, static_cast<char*>(&msg->target_id), sizeof(int));

    // encode numFloats
    std::memcpy(&buffer[0] + HEADER_LENGTH + sizeof(int), static_cast<char*>(&numFloats), sizeof(size_t));

    // encode the vector of float
    std::memcpy(&buffer[0] + HEADER_LENGTH + sizeof(int) + sizeof(size_t),
                static_cast<char*>(&bbox[0]), sizeof(float)*numFloats);

    dst_len = HEADER_LENGTH + len;
}
```